# Is Combines Publisher.subscribe(_ subject) leaking sometimes?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am getting weird memory leaks in Combine. When wiring up the model of a view I need to connect a `PassThroughSubject` in my view model with a `PassThroughSubject` in my business logic. The `viewModel` gets regenerated with the view and the business logic `model` stays the same and persists over time.

I use the code below to connect. The one using `sink` does not leak, the one using `subscribe` leaks.

The reference to self does not seem to be the problem as the class that runs the connection logic is properly cleaned up (I also created a weak variable that I passed to subscribe). Also the viewModel is being cleaned up - with the subscriptions. Only a loop containing Combine classes stays. (see Image below)

It does not seem to be a temporary glitch of memory graph as the object count reflect the number of times I regenerated the view (and the viewModel) and I checked the reference count of the objects with CFGetRetainCount - and they reflect the links displayed in memory graph.

I would very much understand what's going on here. Any clues? My mistake? Known issue? Bug in Combine?

```
   // not leaking 
   viewModel.triggerSubject
        .sink { [weak self] trigger in
            self?.model.triggerSubject.send(trigger)            }
        .store(in: &viewModel.subscriptions)
    
    // leaking
    viewModel.triggerSubject
        .subscribe(model.triggerSubject)
        .store(in: &viewModel.subscriptions)
```

Here is the Memory Graph:

[image: Memory Graph]

And the issues reported by XCode:

[image: Memory Issues]

Comment: `PassthroughSubject` is a class, so it's a reference type. The upstream holds a strong reference to it

Comment: Yup - but shouldn't the stream get cleaned up with my viewModel going out of scope and the subscriptions being cleaned up? Also the upstream is gone in the memory graph and the reference count only reflects the circular dependencies between the Combine classes?

Comment: I think it should, yeah... unless I'm missing something, but hard to say for sure without seeing some other relevant parts of your code.

Comment: If the rest of the code is relevant - then there is a problem anyway... All I do is connect 2 Subjects... actually too easy of a case to be missed by Apple. But it’s actually what I’m doing. I will try to replicate it in an easier case.

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I'm facing this right now and either I completely misunderstand something or there is some very serious issue with Combine